# Error al hacer update en laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Hola estoy obteniendo el error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'titu_2_ing' cannot be null (SQL: update `sections` set `titu_2_ing` = , `titu_2_esp` = , `desc_2_ing` = , `desc_2_esp` = , `titu_3_ing` = , `titu_3_esp` = , `desc_3_ing` = , `desc_3_esp` = , `titu_4_ing` = , `titu_4_esp` = , `desc_4_ing` = , `desc_4_esp` = , `updated_at` = 2018-03-08 18:11:06 where `id` = 2)
```

Como si estuviera enviando mis inputs vacios y estan asi, pondre solo unos inputs

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('about_update') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }} 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_registro" value="2" /> <!-- Valor del registro -->
                        <!-- TITULO -->
                        <div class="row justify-content-between" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
                                                                                border-radius: 5px;
                                                                                background: #f0f3f5;
                                                                                padding: 0.7rem 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem;">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h4 style="color: #0b4650;"><strong>ABOUT US/EDIT</strong></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 3rem;">
                                <input style="color: gray; border: none; width: 17rem; background: none;" value="ÚLTIMA EDICIÓN {{ $sectionInfo->updated_at }}" class="field left" readonly="readonly" name="updated_at">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                

                    <!-- BOTONES GUARDAR / CERRAR -->
                    <div class="row" style="    text-align: right;
                                                margin-top: 1rem;
                                                margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button type="button" class="btn" style="background: #065e6e; color: white; width: 7rem;">CERRAR</button>
                            <button type="SUBMIT" class="btn" style="background: #00a751; color: white; width: 7rem;">ACTUALIZAR</button>
                        </div>    
                    </div>

                    <!-- TITULOS 1-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <input type="text" name="titu_1_ing" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <input type="text" name="titu_1_esp" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_1_esp }}" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- DESCRIPCIONES 1-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <textarea name="desc_1_ing" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_ing }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <textarea name="desc_1_esp" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_1_esp }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <!-- TITULOS 2-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <input type="text" name="titu_1_ing" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_2_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <input type="text" name="titu_1_esp" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_2_esp }}" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.3rem;  background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- DESCRIPCIONES 2-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <textarea name="desc_1_ing" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_2_ing }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6" style="padding-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                            <textarea name="desc_1_esp" rows="30" cols="80" style=" width: 100%; padding: 0.8rem;  height: 10rem; background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">{{ $sectionInfo->desc_2_esp }}</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Y en mis routes tengo

Route::get('about_us', 'HomeAboutController@indexAbout')->name('about_us');
Route::POST('about_update', 'HomeAboutController@updateus')->name('about_update');

de manera que en mi metodo updateus coloco lo siguiente:

```
public function updateus(Request $request)
{
    $sectionInfo = Section::find($request->get('id_registro'));
    $sectionInfo->titu_1_ing = $request->get('titu_1_ing');
    $sectionInfo->titu_1_esp = $request->get('titu_1_esp');
    $sectionInfo->desc_1_ing = $request->get('desc_1_ing');
    $sectionInfo->desc_1_esp = $request->get('desc_1_esp');

    $sectionInfo->titu_2_ing = $request->get('titu_2_ing');
    $sectionInfo->titu_2_esp = $request->get('titu_2_esp');
    $sectionInfo->desc_2_ing = $request->get('desc_2_ing');
    $sectionInfo->desc_2_esp = $request->get('desc_2_esp');

    $sectionInfo->titu_3_ing = $request->get('titu_3_ing');
    $sectionInfo->titu_3_esp = $request->get('titu_3_esp');
    $sectionInfo->desc_3_ing = $request->get('desc_3_ing');
    $sectionInfo->desc_3_esp = $request->get('desc_3_esp');

    $sectionInfo->titu_4_ing = $request->get('titu_4_ing');
    $sectionInfo->titu_4_esp = $request->get('titu_4_esp');
    $sectionInfo->desc_4_ing = $request->get('desc_4_ing');
    $sectionInfo->desc_4_esp = $request->get('desc_4_esp');
    $sectionInfo->save();
    return redirect('about_us');
}
```

Lo raro es que ya hice esto mismo pero con otra vista de manera que todo es casi igual excepto que este tiene id = 2 , lei la doc de laravel a ver si debia poner un key en el modelo y decia que si tiene un campo id lo toma automaticamente como llave primaria entonces no se que podria estar ocurriendo

Comment: ¿qué imprime un dump($request->all()) en el controlador? Y también un dump($sectionInfo) después de la primera línea

Comment: como veo eso? abri el inspector de codigo y tipee: dump($sectionInfo)
VM6701:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: dump is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM6701:1
dump($request->all())
VM6735:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que los nombres de los input/text area a partir del segundo tienen el nombre de los mismos que el primero ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="titu_1_ing" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_2_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
```

en vez de

```
<input type="text" name="titu_2_ing" value="{{ $sectionInfo->titu_2_ing }}" style=" width: 100%;   padding: 0.3rem;   background: #e3e6e9; border: solid 1px #8181825c;">
```

y asi para los demas por eso te marca el error es como si le enviaras solo los titulos y descripcion 1